# Perl:Subnetting Example snippet?

Tags: perl, network-programming

I am looking for an example perl code for obtaining subnets of a network
For example

10.0.0.0/8 can be broken down in 2 /9  == 10.0.0.0/9 , 10.128.0.0/9

or 8 /20s from a /17 =  10.1.1.1 /17 to  /20
 10.1.0.0/20, 10.1.16.0/20, 10.1.32.0/20, 10.1.48.0/20, 10.1.64.0/20,10.1.80.0/20 , 10.1.96.0/20 , 10.1.112.0/20.

Any ideas on how to do this in perl please?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are attempting to achieve.  If you can edit your question to add a non-trivial example of something you would like to solve programmatically, perhaps you can avoid receiving more close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Net::CIDR::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aCIDR%3a%3aLite) and/or [Net::CIDR](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aCIDR).